# Base Case in Recursive Staircase?

Tags: c++, recursion

I was solving this Question:
A child is running up a staircase with n steps and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can run up the stairs.

I tried to solve this using this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ways(int N){
    if(N == 1 || N == 2) {
        return N;
    }else if(N <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ways(N-1)+ways(N-2)+ways(N-3);
}

int main() {

    cout<<ways(4);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output : 4

Expected Output : 7**

I am taking f(0<=N) = 0, f(1) = 1 and f(2) = 2, where f(x) is number of ways to climb xth Stair.
But, it is giving wrong output. I then looked at the solution at observed that f(0) = 1 was also considered, which according to me should be f(0) = 0 as there are no ways to climb 0th Stair.

Comment: are answers to all other cases correct?

Comment: Since you're given `f(0) = 1`, you should return 1 if `N` is 0. You could argue that there's only one way to climb no stairs (by doing nothing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change following:

```
if(N == 1 || N == 0) {
    return 1;
} else if(N == 2) {
    return 2;
}
```

Consider scenario when three steps are there. last return will execute
ways(n-1) + ways(n-2) + **ways(n-3)**
which means
ways(2) + ways(1) + **ways(0)**

Here third part represents how many ways can child climb using 3 stairs at time. That would be returned as 0 but that should be 1. He can climb three stairs in using 3 steps in 1 way

Comment: What is meant by left ways?